# Add DLL in LinqPad 6

Tags: linqpad

I'm using LINQPad 6 and I can't figure out how to add System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement DLL.  I see where I can pick from NuGet stuff, but not standard windows DLL.  Previous versions used to list all the DLL and let me pick directly from there.  Is that gone?

Comment: That is gone, but you can use F4 Add/Browse... and find a DLL to add a reference to. A Nuget package is easier.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement is part of the standard netcore library, but is available as a [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement/) package.

If it was part of the standard library, then you would not need to add the dll, but just reference it.

> ```
> There's no longer an option to add Framework assembly references. In keeping with Visual
> Studio, all .NET Core Framework assemblies are referenced automatically.
> ```

From the *Things that behave differently in LINQPad 6* section of https://www.linqpad.net/LINQPad6.aspx